# Spark Java isn't recognizing static files and serving them

Tags: java, spark-java

This was working before.
I have a request for 2 things.

```
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.png">
```

and a style,

```
background-image: background.jpg;
```

but it doesn't recognize and returns with 404 not found.
I have set

```
Spark.staticFileLocation("/public/");
```

and made sure that it is correct

```
src/main/resources/public/*.jpg
```

How can I fix?

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove terminating slash

```
staticFileLocation("/public");
```